# Can HTTPS be used for LAN to LAN connections?

Tags: networking, security, encryption, lan

I have to connect to another LAN device across an open LAN. The other LAN device has a LAN GUI, which is protected by a username and password. The problem is that if i connect to the LAN GUI in entering my username and password these will be sent plain text.

If i was to type `https://` in front of the LAN IP of the device with the LAN GUI, would the username and password used to log in be sent encrypted across the LAN, there would be no certificate enabled, so it would show as insecure but would the encryption still be inplace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS can be used with any connection that can transport TCP. However, HTTPS is not magically available. The server has to support it. Most simple devices like SOHO routers, printers, ... do not.

For HTTPS, a certificate is always required. It can be a self-signed certificate though, which the browser would then reject by default, just like you described. The connection (if the warning is dismissed) would still be encrypted, yes.

Comment: to add onto this: if you can configure TLS/SSL and other web access settings on the device before-hand (either manually at its UI or by connecting a machine directly to it), you can potentially enable HTTPS without ever having to send your credentials over unencrypted

Comment: Would i know if my LAN device (a voip phone) supports HTTPS using a self signed certificate, if i log into it using https://192.168... and it still loads the GUI ? Despite the browser saying "unsecure" ?

Comment: If it loads, it supports HTTPS, yes. If it did not, you’d get a timeout or connection refused error.